# Nginx server_name redirect

Tags: linux, nginx, web-server, redirect, website

I am doing an mobile page redirect for my website,it success, but unfortunately it stay at the same domain name, 
exmaple: when i go johnson.com by phone it should go to m.johnson.com(Yes, this is correct), but when i go baby.com by phone when it redirect also went to m.johnson.com, it should be go to m.baby.com, it only will be redirect to the first server name in mobile.conf.

this is main.conf

```
server {    #www
    listen       80;#HTTP 的端口
    server_name  .johnson.com .baby.com
    root    /web/abc/www ;
    index   index.jhtml index.html index.htm;

    charset utf-8;
    access_log  logs/abc.access.log ;
    include config/mobile_redirect.conf;

    error_page 404 404.jsp;
    error_page 500 502 503 500.jsp;
}
```

> Blockquote

mobile_redirect.conf

```
 set $mobile_rewrite do_not_perform;

if ($http_user_agent ~* "(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od|ad)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino") {
  set $mobile_rewrite perform;
}

if ($http_user_agent ~* "^(1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-)") {
  set $mobile_rewrite perform;
}

if ($mobile_rewrite = perform) {
  rewrite ^ $scheme://m.$server_name/wap/ redirect;
  break;
}
```

> Blockquote

mobile.conf

```
server {
        listen          80;
        server_name  m.johnson.com m.baby.com;
        root            /web/abc/www/;
        index           index.html index.jsp index.jhtml index.htm;
        charset         utf-8;
        access_log      logs/abc-mobile.access.log ;
        error_page 404 404.jsp;
        error_page 500 502 503 500.jsp;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to put your mobile redirection within the applicable server block, and define different server blocks for each mobile site. A little duplication now and overhead to jeep up, but makes things easier to tweak later if requirements change.

The key change is

```
server {
  listen       80;
  server_name  johnson.com

  # Add redirect detection
  if ($mobile_rewrite = perform) {
    rewrite ^ $scheme://m.johnson.com/wap/ redirect;
    break;
  }
}

server {
  listen       80;
  server_name  baby.com

  # Add redirect detection
  if ($mobile_rewrite = perform) {
    rewrite ^ $scheme://m.baby.com/wap/ redirect;
    break;
  }
}
```

**Second option**

The $host variable contains the host name - eg www.example.com. So if your user is on example.com this would work, but not on www.example.com. In that case you'd need to do some regular expression work to remove the www from the start of the host name. I've tested that this works, on the non-www domain, but you should be able to work it out from here if you understand or can learn regular expressions.

```
if ($mobile_rewrite = perform) {
  rewrite ^ $scheme://m.$host/wap/ redirect;
  break;
}
```

However Google/SEO discourages this, they strongly encourage responsive design.

Comment: HI Tim, Thanks for replying me, but i have almost 20 domain, i can't do this, i need a more Convenience way to go.

Comment: I've added a second option. I have half a dozen domains, I configure them individually, but 20 could be a nuisance if you need to change them all regularly.

Comment: @JohnsonGoey If something helped and worked, please consider upvoting that answer too.

Comment: Yes,i earning my reputation.